# Clickhouse: how to convert date to long integer?

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, clickhouse

I have date as a string field in form of '2018-01-02 12:12:22', what is the right way to convert it to long int timestamp in ClickHouse SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
:) SELECT toUInt64(toDateTime('2018-01-02 12:12:22'));

SELECT toUInt64(toDateTime('2018-01-02 12:12:22'))

┌─toUInt64(toDateTime('2018-01-02 12:12:22'))─┐
│                                  1514884342 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────┘

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec.
```

Comment: you can also use toFloat64 instead of toUInt64 - it will reveal fractional part of timestamp if it was inserted

Answer (score 0):

My query returns a different result

```
SELECT toUInt64(toDateTime('2018-01-02 12:12:22', 'UTC'))

┌─toUInt64(toDateTime('2018-01-02 12:12:22', 'UTC'))─┐
│                                         1514895142 │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```